# Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема с int(sys.argv[1])?

Tags: python

Возникает ошибка с `int(sys.argv[1])`:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: А у меня не возникает, например. Какая проблема-то?

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: А что вы ожидаете от данного кода вместо этого?

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv` - это список параметров скрипта. В этом списке всегда есть хотя бы один элемент - имя скрипта или пустая строка, если к `sys.argv` обращаются из интерактивной оболочки (запустить python, и в нем вывести содержимое `sys.argv`).

Далее, если в скрипт передаются какие-то параметры, то они появляются в `sys.argv`. Например, скрипт:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

Запускаем так:

```
python test.py 1 abc def
```

Получаем:

```
['test.py', '1', 'abc', 'def']
```

Если не передать никаких парметров:

```
python test.py
```

Получим только имя скрипта:

```
['test.py']
```

Длина этого списка 1, первый элемент имеет индекс 0. Если обратиться к элементу с индексом 1, этот индекс будет уже за пределами списка, в итоге получим ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Как эту проблему решить:

- во-первых, в скрипт нужно передать параметр, если вы это собирались сделать, но не сделали.
- во-вторых, нужно проверять длину `sys.argv`, и если передано меньше параметров, чем ожидалось, то как-то сообщить о проблеме пользователю.
- если у вас ожидается числовой параметр, а пользователь передал в скрипт не число (пользователи бывают очень изобретательны), то скрипт прервется с ошибкой `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`. Подобные проблемы также нужно уметь обрабатывать. В данном случае можно обернуть преобразование параметра к целому числу в блок try-except с обработкой исключения `ValueError`. [Небольшое руководство по обработке исключений](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/isklyucheniya-v-python-konstrukciya-try-except-dlya-obrabotki-isklyuchenij.html).

Пример кода с обработкой возможных ситуаций:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print('Недостаточно параметров')
else:
    try:
        print(int(sys.argv[1]))
    except ValueError:
        print('Параметром скрипта должно быть число')
```